# Is there an equivalent to DOM inspector for Android Native Layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, google-chrome-devtools

When developing HTML5 webpages with CSS and javascript, I've found DOM inspectors like  [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) extremely helpful in root causing which CSS styles are being applied to which HTML5 elements on a webpage. The interface allows you to see the actual layout on the left, along with the DOM, with the CSS being applied to the page dynamically at that moment.

My question is - does any tool exist that is similar to this for Android applications? Is there a way to identify which xml styles are being applied to which elements in an activity or application? This would be particularly helpful in seeing the "default" [styles.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) in an application.

Does anyone have any suggested tools to help figure out what styles are being applied to each element in an activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not keep the styling information after a View is created. The closest thing you can use is a tool called HierarchyViewer. You can learn more about this tool here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html

You should also checkout http://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer to be able to use HierarchyViewer on production devices (we plan on making this requirement obsolete.)

Comment: Very cool. some feedback - when I ran HierarchyViewer, I received a message saying that the standalone tool is deprecated and has been replaced by monitor. I then opened monitor, went to the Hierarchy perspective, but immediately received an error "Unable to get view server version from device \n Unable to get view server protocol version from device \n Unable to debug device: samsung-nexus_10"  -Any thoughts as to why that'd be the case? perhaps high level restrictions? (I'm running on an app deployed via debug in Android Studio)

Comment: Also worth mentioning is **`uiautomatorviewer`**, which, while a bit more limited than Hierarchy View, works today on production devices without having to modify the app's source code to include `ViewServer`. http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#uianalysis With respect to your problems in your comment above, as Romain noted, you cannot use Hierarchy View on hardware, unless you add `ViewServer` to your project.

Comment: Having downloaded ViewServer, I think I understand that I need to add the class into my project and use it as you describe in your source code.  I had originally thought your statement "...to be able to use HierarchyViewer on production devices" meant that you could use it on devices which had USB debugging enabled.

Comment: Also don't forget about [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) which will simplify the process of obtaining the View tree and interacting (i.e. touch) with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an app for Android which aspires to be a close match to developer tools known from web browsers. Of course it's only a mere startup and can't match functionality of counterparts designed to inspect web pages, also it can't match what is possible with official desktop tools like the [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) from the [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/).

It has one advantage however, it works offline (directly on the device, no need to use ADB, any SDK etc.).

If you are interested, enjoy the [Developer Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsisle.developerassistant).

[image]

Comment: Another advantage is that it allows us to inspect the layout of activities/views that don't belong to our app. Android Studio's Layout Inspector tool does not allow this. Thanks for putting this tool together! Previously I was using 'uiautomatorviewer' but that no longer works.